# How to add new packages to TeXStudio

Tags: packages, natbib, texstudio

I'm completely new to writing in LaTeX and am therefore starting up with a pre-made `report` template. However when I just try to compile the template I get the message that following file is required.

```
tex\latex\natbib\natbib.sty
```

So I've downloaded the `natbib` package but where do I save the files?
Appreciate any help and advice to get started with TeXStudio and how to add packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: As Matthias' answer says, the editor doesn't really have anything to do with this, could you say which TeX distribution (MikTeX, MacTeX, TeX Live, ...) you have installed?

Comment: I've installed MikTex 2.9.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Editor has actually nothing to do with the LaTeX System. The packages are installed and updated typically with a package manager from the LaTeX distribution - not with the Editor.

If you are using miktex then start the "package manager" and with Tex Live "TeX Live Manager" and add the missing package(s).

If you want to avoid problems with missing packages it is a good practice to install all available packages. That way you hardly ever miss a package again.

If a package is not available in the repository you could as well copy the .sty file to the place where your .tex file is located. However this should always be the exception.

Comment: I've installed "texlive-full" yet I can't find Tex Live Manager. How/where should I find it?

Comment: I believe the command is `tlmgr`

Comment: @Matthias If no .sty file is available then what to do? I am using Texstudio with Mistek distribution and want to install a standalone package, it has only .ins file in it. Thanks

Comment: in Ubuntu/Debian `sudo apt install texlive-full` should do the trick