# Standard preamble for theses

Tags: document-classes, best-practices, thesis

I will start write my master thesis very soon. In it I like to have a preamble.
I use `basic-miktex-2.9.5105` and as an editor TeXmaker -- installed on a windows machine.

Also: can I find a distro or bundle like MikTeX (or a version of it) containing all current LaTeX packages?

Comment: If you want a distribution with all the packages, simply use texlive (http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). Works fine on windows.

Comment: I would not search for a preamble, better start with a basic document class (for example `book`) and while you go, add the packages you need.

Comment: It's *very* easy to install missing packages with MikTeX Package Manager.

Comment: @Bernard I saw a video on youtube about the installation of package, and I find it difficult a bit, can you help me?

Comment: There is no standard preamble for any thesis!

Comment: I can, of course, but what's so difficult?

Comment: Regarding the installation of new packages you might want to read: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125918/how-to-add-new-packages-to-texmaker, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181024/how-to-add-new-packages-to-texstudio,

Comment: Be careful though: your university may have specific requirements about how a thesis or dissertation should look. Check with them; perhaps a template is available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally I'd recommend to build every document from scratch because *every* document has its own requirements. However, looking at your question a second time, I thought there are indeed things *nearly every* thesis will need to do. So here is a "minimal working preamble" for theses:

```
\documentclass{report} % or even: book | or the koma classes: scrreprt, scrbook
% or for a small thesis 'article' or the corresponding 'scrartcl'
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[<encoding>]{fontenc} % probabilly: T1
\usepackage[<encoding>]{inputenc} % probabilly: utf8
%\usepackage{palatino} % just as a matter of taste
\usepackage[<your language(s)>]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry} % and then \geometry{<settings>}
\usepackage{csquotes} % probabilly with the option: autostyle=true
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\usepackage{natbib} % or biblatex
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{ {images/} } % or whatever your "images"-directory is
\usepackage{todonotes} % or fixme
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

...

%declaration environment
\usepackage{titling}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@decltotoc
\newcommand\declarationname{Declaration of Authorship}
\newcommand\ltx@sectionings{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,subparagraph}
\newcommand\decl@rationsect{chapter}
\ifdefined\chapter\else\renewcommand\decl@rationsect{section}\fi
\newenvironment{declaration}[2][\decl@rationsect]{%
  \edef\@tempa{\decl@rationsect}%
  \edef\reserved@a{#1}%
  \gdef\theplace{#2}%
  \@decltotocfalse
  \@ifundefined{#1}{\@latex@warning{#1 not defined}}{%
    \@tempswafalse%
    \@for\sec:=\ltx@sectionings\do{\ifx\sec\reserved@a\@tempswatrue\fi}%
    \if@tempswa\let\@tempa\reserved@a\else
      \@latex@warning{#1 is not a sectioning command, so I overrode it}\fi}
  \csname\@tempa\endcsname*{\declarationname}
  \if@decltotoc\addcontentsline{toc}{\@tempa}{\declarationname}\fi
}{%
  \par\vskip6em\par\noindent\theauthor\hfill\theplace,\space\thedate\par
  \global\let\declaration\gobble@env
  \global\let\enddeclaration\relax
  \global\expandafter\let\csname enddeclaration*\endcsname\relax
}
\expandafter\def\csname declaration*\endcsname{\let\@decltotocfalse\@decltotoctrue\declaration}
\expandafter\let\csname enddeclaration*\endcsname\enddeclaration
\def\gobble@env{\@ifnextchar[{\@gobble@env}{\@gobble@env[]}}
\def\@gobble@env[#1]{\@bsphack\@@gobble@env}
\def\@@gobble@env#1\end{\@esphack\end}
\makeatother
```

The last part of the code defines a `declaration` environment as a declaration of authorship mostly is an integral part of (nearly) each thesis. Its use is prety straightforward:

```
\begin{declaration}{City}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
  sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{declaration}
```

If it should appear in the toc you can say `\begin{declaration*}{City}...\end{declaration*}`.

## Remarks

- For a bigger thesis you will most likely need a documentclass that supports `\chapter`s in the sectioning. Anyways, there are a few more classes to consider here. For this you may want to see the [CTAN class overview](https://www.ctan.org/topic/class).
- A few packages are really somehow default everywhere (assuming pdfLaTeX): [`microtype`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) to include pdfTeXs mi­cro-ty­po­graphic ex­ten­sions, [`inputenc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) and [`fontenc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) to control encodings; if you are using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX those packages are unusable
- [`babel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) to gurantee language-dependent tasks are done correctly
- Every university places (most likely ridiculous) requirements regarding the page [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry)
- You will most likely need to quote: [`csquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes); and as a supplement [`ellipsis`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ellipsis), which corrects the often wrong white space of `\dots` in text-mode
- You will for sure need to cite in a customised style: [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib), [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), etc.
- In case you have external figures: [`graphicx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)
- It comes in handy to store to-do-notes while writing on a big project -- that have to be excluded in the final version, hence [`todonotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes); often people like to use the alternative [`fixme`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixme) package as it overcomes boundaries of the `todonotes` package regarding the placement of the notes
- Often you want to have clickable cross references: [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref); note that you have to load `hyperref` (nearly) as the last package to ensure that your document compiles properly. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) you can find a thorough discussion on this topic -- for instance you have to load `geometry` after `hyperref`; the above preamlbe is technically wrong so to speak; it is just on a higher position because of the "hirarchy" in the listing
- The last two ones are more or less optional: [`fancyhdr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) is the standard tool to set headers and footers and [`emptypage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/emptypage) may be included if you want empty pages to be actually empty
- In addition to the `todonotes` package you might also want to use the [`comment`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package as a pseudo version control system
- Depending on your subject or if you need to produce drawings and diagrams inside of LaTeX you might also need

  - the AMS bundle: [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), [`amssymb`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amssymb), [`amsthm`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)
  - [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)
  - [`tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), [`xypic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic)

## Addendum

It is worth noting that the `memoir` documentation dedicates a whole chapter (21. "An example thesis design", pp. 357-375) to explain how to design a thesis style. There might be a few clues about additional features one might want to incorporate into the own preamble. However, it should also be said that this manual focuses on the thesis style from a package/class designer point of view.

Comment: I usually use `fixme` instead of `todonotes` as with the `layout=marginnote,innerlayout=noinline` the notes can be used anywhere, whereas `\todo` cannot (as it is using `\marginpar`) other than that I mostly agree with the list.

Comment: Perhaps add that if you are using XeTeX or LuaTeX then skip the `inputenc`/`fontenc` part.

Comment: I'd consider moving `hyperref` last and commenting that _very few_ packages should come after it.

Comment: @daleif and @JosephWright -- thank you! Ill add a remark on the `\todo` section and clarify matters regarding 'inputenc/fontenc' and `hyperref`

Comment: The `memoir` class manual (`texdoc memoir`) provides an extensive example setting up the typesetting for a thesis.