# Installation error "paracol" package

Tags: page, paracol

the "paracol" package when I give it to install appears the following message "File` paracol.sty 'not found. " Maybe I'm making some mistake but I do not detect it.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.6}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{leftcolumn}
        The environment may also be restarted
        anywhere you like as shown here. ...
    \end{leftcolumn}
    \begin{rightcolumn}
        source
    \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
Now the aurthor will do ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: I use TeXstudio in Windows 10.

Comment: TeXStudio is just an editor. By distribution I mean MikTeX or TeXLive.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181024/how-to-add-new-packages-to-texstudio

Comment: And https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution

Comment: I use  MikTeX as distribution.

Comment: If the second question I linked to solves your problem, then this question can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @David Purton When the package is installed from MiKTeX as administrator, the following message appears "The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state. The MiKTeX project page(https://miktex.org) might have more info." then wait.

Comment: Indeed. [miktex.org](https://miktex.org/) seems to be down at present. Try again a bit later.

Comment: @SamuelDiaz I think that you can download `paracol` from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol?lang=en) instead (it's not down).