# Package not found in texstudio

Tags: pdftex, texlive, texstudio

I am using texstudio to write a report. I am getting below error though :

```
File `mathabx.sty' not found. \RequirePackage
```

It seem texlive manages the package in texstudio .

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0
```

I had checked following links :[Link1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181024/how-to-add-new-packages-to-texstudio), [Link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984051/how-do-i-install-packages-to-texstudio) but couldn't resolve problem

I tried installing package wit tlgmr as above but wasn't successful. How should I install package. My system is ubuntu 18.04 and texstudio version is 2.12.6

Comment: try to install texlive-fonts-extra

Comment: thanks it solved my issue. Do you know how to install specific package form tex-live-fonts-extra ?